# How can I stop GNOME Keyring from offering to remember a keyring password?

Tags: gnome-keyring

I use a Firefox extension to put my passwords into GNOME Keyring. I protect this keyring with a password. Whenever I start Firefox, GNOME prompts me for the keyring password:

[image]

However, notice how each time this happens, there's a checkbox to automatically unlock this keyring on login. I don't want this to happen, so I have to uncheck the box every time. How can I make it so that this checkbox is *never* checked automatically?

I've tried Googling for both a description of my problem and for GNOME Keyring docs, I've poked around the relevant dconf values, I've looked at the Arch Wiki page on GNOME Keyring and even looked at `gnome-keyring-daemon(1)`. All with no luck.

Comment: Gnome Keyring prompts me only once at the begin of a session when I start to use ssh-keys. Could it be possible that it has something to do with the Firefox extension?

Comment: @bersch does it prompt your for the login keyring password? the extension uses a different keyring with a distinct password from the login keyring. it's this password that GNOME wants to remember (in the login keyring).

Comment: just the normal behavior.

Comment: @bersch I don't understand what you're saying. I'm asking for the name of the keyring that you get prompted for.

Comment: just the normal behavior means, that gnome-keyring works like expected. The extension you use cause probably the errors.

Comment: @bersch you still haven't answered my question. _what is the name of the keyring that you get prompted for_?

Comment: did you read my question properly? _there is no error_. it's an expected behavior of GNOME Keyring. I want to change said behavior.

Comment: sorry, that I did not understand you Q. It'll be fine you could rephrase it.

Comment: @bersch now that I read this again, I seem a little rude, so sorry - I'm adding a screenshot that should hopefully clear up your confusion.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and it ONLY appears when using the same extension for Thunderbird (the checkbox is checked every time regardless of whether I checked it before or not). It's a wild guess but maybe it's related to the way the extension asks for this keyring access? Maybe there's some "always true" type of argument being passed to the Gnome API's method every time? Also, it used to happen for Firefox too but extension for Firefox doesn't work anymore (due to Mozilla's Sync service push).